# How does this test run the queries, are they delegates? What is Action<int>?

Tags: c#, ado.net

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/PerformanceTests.cs

Confused, `PerformanceTest.Run` initializes the list by adding test objects.

How does it actually run the query?

I'm guessing it is the line:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
{
    foreach (var test in this.OrderBy(ignore => rand.Next()))
    {
        test.Watch.Start();
        test.Iteration(i);
        test.Watch.Stop();
    }
}
```

`test.iteration(i);`

But how? Is this a delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Action` type is the key here. [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx?ppud=4) is a built-in delegate type that has no return value and (in this case) takes one parameter of type `T`. `Iteration` is the property of type `Action<int>` where the test action is stored in `Test` object, and `()` operator just invokes the method with `i` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, `Action<int>` is a delegate that accepts an integer as an argument (in this case, the iteration number).